# Как подключить bootstrap select?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

На форуме показан пример, что он изображён так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том как подключить `bootstrap select`

```html
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Comment: И возможно ли его реализовать с <li>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Вопрос в том как подключить bootstrap select

Вот так, подключается.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { // 
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

```html
<!-------- head -------->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<!-------- end head -------->

<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>


<!-------- in the end of the body -------->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<!-------- end of the body -------->
```